# Four vectors are connected in series and head to tail

Tags: vectors

I have been trying to solve this problem for a while. I would appreciate it if you can point out where I am doing wrong.

Four vectors are connected in series and head to tail. The first vector has the tail in point `(0,0)`. The vectors are `(2i ,1j), (2i ,2j), (-4i ,3j)` and `(ai,bj)`. Find the vector `(ai, bj)` so the series connection ends up in the point`(0,0)`.
Find also the angle between the y-axis and `(ai, bj)`.

### Below is how I did

`(2i ,1j), (2i ,2j), (-4i ,3j)`

```
(2i * 2i * (-4i) + (1j * 2j * 3j) 
= -16 + 6 
= -10

||a|| = √(2^2 + 1^2) = √(5) 
||b|| = √(2^2 + 2^2) = √(8) 
||c|| = √((-4)^2 + 3^2) = √(25) = 5 

θ = cos^-1(-10/(√(5) * √(8) * 5)) 
= 108.04
```

#### But in the book, the solution is 104.04, I don't know how they got that. any help is appriciated.

Comment: "Connected"? I believe you are supposed to *add* the vectors...

Comment: $2i*2i*(-4i) is meaningless. End to end means add.

Comment: The sum of the first three vectors is $0\vec{i}+6\vec{j}$, so $a\vec{i}+b\vec{j}=0\vec{i}-6\vec{j}$ which makes an angle of $180^\circ$ with the $y$-axis.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to answer it.

```
i: 1+2+3+(-4)+a = -1 => a = -2
j: 1+1+2+3+b    = -1 => b = -8

so!
(ai,bj) = (-2i,-8j).

The angle between the x-axis and (ai, bj) is:
(-2i,-8j) * (1i, 0j) = -2 

and 

0 = cos^-1(-2/(√2^2 + 8^2 * √1^2 + 0^2)) = 104.04°
```